# How do I undeploy a meteor application?

Tags: meteor

I've deployed an application with:
`meteor deploy a-meteor-app.meteor.com`.

Is there a way for me to undeploy from meteor.com?

Comment: For more info on the command line tools, you can always try `meteor deploy --help` or also `meteor help deploy`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the [Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteordeploy):

> To delete an application you've deployed, specify the --delete option along with the site.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Wijsman, I should have searched the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 91):

Suppose I have deployed an app on the url :- http://anotherajax.meteor.com/ .

Then, to remove this deployed app, Run this Command:-

```
meteor deploy --delete anotherajax.meteor.com
```

Comment: This is a more complete answer to the question.

Comment: This should really be more detailed in the `--help` thanks for you answer

Comment: this should be the answer. +1